# JavaScript block display doesn't work with two functions in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been able to create some expanding DIVs that toggle on checkbox click. Most relevant code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggle(obj) {
          var obj=document.getElementById(obj);
          if (obj.style.display == "block") obj.style.display = "none";
          else obj.style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<input id="repeatunlimited" type="checkbox" name="chk_sldr" "javascript: void(0);" onClick="toggle('q1')">stuff<br>
<div id="q1" style="display:none;">
More stuff
</div>
```

This will toggle the expanding DIV so that when clicked once, it will expand, then clicked again, it will collapse.

BUT

I also want a function that just forces an expand on the same q1 element, so that I have both the ability to toggle, AND to just expand.

I've added the following to my code in addition to the above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function expand(ExpandObj) {
          var ExpandObj=document.getElementById(ExpandObj);
          ExpandObj.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

And call it with this:

```
expand(q1);
```

This works fine for IE, but causes the content displayed in Firefox to freeze. Just wondering if there is something else I can do to get it to work?

Comment: What happens if you call it as `expand('q1');` instead? Your function is expecting a string.

Comment: my bad, I meant to include the quotes in my question.  It still hangs up even with the quotes FYI.

Comment: If you *then* rename either the function parameter or the internal `var`, so they don't both have the same name, what happens?

Comment: So rename either the function parameter of the internal VAR on the new function?  The function didn't work in that case, and I get an error in firebug.

Comment: Rename the parameter. Make sure you use the *new* name when calling `getElementById`. Now what happens? And *what* error did you get in firebug?

Comment: That doesn't work unfortunately.  It still freezes the browser, but doesn't produce a firebug error.

Comment: Works here, no freeze: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zvPVEK. Please include code *in the question*, with typos fixed, that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Thanks Paul.  Your codepen code only has the one function.  This works fine with mine too.  It's when I have both functions that I have the problem.  So function 1 is "toggle" and function 2 is "expand" only.  Does that make sense?

Comment: Okay, well I was not able to repeat the problem in codepen using firefox, so this code must be badly interacting with other code elsewhere.  The call to the function in question does appear within another function that is doing lots of stuff.  Still the above was REALLY helpful to get me to this point, so thank you.  Not sure how I can mark it as an answer . . .

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quotes!!

You have to to call the function like this:

```
expand( 'q1');
```

Easy right?